# How can I set up a data structure while writing to a file?

Tags: c++

I have been writing the following code in C++. So far, I have been stuck with 3 problem. Also very new
Putting the data from input into a structure.
Search function keeps returning true, so something is wrong there
it seems get Information() is in some kind of loop, because whenever I run it in main, it just keeps running forever. The code is attached below.

*MAIN.CPP*

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class accountInfo {
private:
    char password[20];
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char username[20];
    float uniqueID;

public:
    void getInformation();
    void storeInformation();
    void editInformation();
    void displayInformation();
    void searchInformation();
};

void accountInfo::getInformation() {
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << "Please enter your second name: ";
    cin >> lastName;
    cout << "Please create a password: ";
    cin >> password;
    cout << "Please choose your username";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Please enter your ID number to open an account: ";
    cin >> uniqueID;
}

void accountInfo::storeInformation() {
    string option;
    string yes("Y");
    string no("N");

    cout << "Would like to save this information? "
         << "\n Y/N";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> option;

    if(option == yes) {
        ofstream MyFile("Records.txt");
        MyFile << firstName;
        MyFile << lastName;
        MyFile << password;
        MyFile << uniqueID;
        MyFile << username;
        MyFile.close();
    } else if(option == no) {
        cout << "Information not saved";
    } else
        cout << "Please choose Y or N";
}

void accountInfo::displayInformation() {
    string myText;
    ifstream MyFile("Records.txt");
    if(MyFile.is_open()) {
        while(getline(MyFile, myText)) {
            cout << myText;
        }
        MyFile.close();
    } else
        cout << "Sorry, Unable to open file at this time";
}

void accountInfo::editInformation() {
    char* newFirstName = firstName;
    char* newLastName = lastName;
    char* newPassword = password;

    cout << "NOTE: Username cannot be changed";
    cout <> newFirstName;
    cout << "Please enter update for last name: ";
    cin >> newLastName;
    cout << "Please enter update for the password: ";
    cin >> newPassword;

    cout << "\nUpdated first name is: " << newFirstName;
    cout << "\nUpdated last name is: " << newLastName;
    cout << "\nUpdated password is : " << newPassword;
}

void accountInfo::searchInformation() {
    ifstream file;
    string searchUsername, g;

    cout << "Enter the username to be searched: ";
    cin >> searchUsername;
    getline(cin, searchUsername);

    file.open("Records.txt", ios::in);
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Cannot find the Records file\nProgram will now exit\n";

        exit(0);
    }

    else {
        while(isalnum(file.peek())) {
            getline(file, g);
            if(g.find(searchUsername, 0) != string::npos) {
                cout << "Username" << searchUsername
                     << " is present and valid in the system" << endl;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
}

int main() {
    int choice;
    accountInfo Instruction{};
    cout << "WELCOME TO PINNACLE BANK";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "\n\tMAIN MENU: " << endl;
    while(true) {
        cout << "\nPlease choose from the following options: ";
        cout << "\nEnter 1 to create a new bank account";
        cout << "\nEnter 2 to show account information";
        cout << "\nEnter 3 to update account information";
        cout << "\nEnter 4 to search information of the account";
        cout << "\nEnter 5 to quit program";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            Instruction.getInformation();
            Instruction.storeInformation();
            cout << "\n-----Taking you back to main menu----";
            break;
        case 2:
            Instruction.displayInformation();
            cout << "\n-----Taking you back to main menu----";
            break;
        case 3:
            Instruction.editInformation();
            cout << "\n-----Taking you back to main menu----";
            break;
        case 4:
            Instruction.searchInformation();
            cout << "\n-----Taking you back to main menu----";
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "\nTHANK YOU FOR USING PINNACLE, \n **YOUR TRUSTED BANK** ";
            exit(0);
        default:
            cout << "\nPlease enter the correct choice: ";
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry about the weird formant, new to Stack Overflow

Comment: `cout <> newFirstName;` - what's up with that?

Comment: You have `cin >> searchUsername;` followed by `getline(cin, searchUsername);`.  Just do one or the other.

Comment: That was definitely a mistake, probably when i was copying and pasting the code..but i have cout <<newFirstName;

Comment: oh okay. Thanks. I eventually used getline